# How to add components to card title container react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am using React-native-elements in my React Native project. I need to add a "+" sign to the right of the card title as shown below, using `react-native-vector-icons`. I went through the docs, but couldn't find anything relevant.

[image]

```js
<Card
   title="Resources"
   titleStyle={{
     textAlign: 'left',
   }}
>
   <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>No resources</Text>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in this [issue](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/918), it is possible to provide `title` with a react component. Therefore, the following works properly.

```js
<Card titleStyle={{textAlign: 'left'}} title={
   <View style={{display: "flex",flexDirection: "row"}}>
     <Text>About me</Text>
     <View style={{flexGrow: 1}} />
     <FIcon name="edit"/> 
   </View>
}>
   <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>{userData.bio}</Text>
</Card>
```